# Struts2 how to override the global interceptor stack for an action

Tags: struts2, overriding, xml-configuration, struts2-interceptors

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="DefaultTEST">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
    <!-- some more interceptors go in here -->
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging" />
</interceptor-stack>

<default-interceptor-ref name="DefaultTEST" />

<action name="welcome">
    <result type="tiles">WELCOME_PAGE</result>
</action>

<action name="">
    <result ...>...</result>
</action>

... <!-- more actions -->
```

So my question is how to override the default interceptor stack so that for welcome action some other interceptors (or interceptor stack) can be loaded while the default one is not.

Comment: Define other stack and use it in action configuration. What is the problem?

Comment: @AleksandrM If I specify another stack for that particular action, in addition to the stack, the default stack will also be triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the interceptors config if you reference an interceptor or interceptors stack in the action config explicitly.

```xml
<action name="welcome">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result type="tiles">WELCOME_PAGE</result>
</action>
```

---

Only `defaultStack` will be executed for `welcome` action. Other actions that don't override the interceptors config in this package will use `DefaultTEST` because it's configured as default.